# ActiveRecord has_many with custom foreign key sql expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, associations

In ActiveRecord, a has_many relationship uses a foreign key column to load the association.  So:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

Person.limit(10).includes(:messages) 
# select * from persons limit 10;
# select messages.* from messages where person_id in (1, 2, 3...)
```

I have a case (and I've seen other people ask for this as well) where I don't want Rails to automatically append the foreign key check to the where clause.  Instead, I might want something like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, 
           :foreign_key => false, 
           :conditions => proc { ["person_id is null or person_id = ?", self.id] }
end

Person.limit(10).includes(:messages)
# select messages.* from messages where person_id is null or person_id in (1, 2, 3...)
```

How can I do this?  To sum up, I don't want ActiveRecord automatically appending the foreign key in the WHERE clause, I want to be able to specify the expression it uses for the association.

I don't want to do this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def messages
    Message.where("person_id is null or person_id = #{ self.id }")
  end
end
```

as that would break eager loading, as far as I know.

I also don't want to use the `finder_sql` option to has_many, as that would break things like `person.messages.where(:id => 1)` or `Person.limit(10).includes(:messages => :image)`

Comment: Possibly another way to ask this same question: is it possible to do a has_many relationship with no foreign key? I could use the :conditions option instead.

Comment: I'd bet there are some good reasons why it's not possible to do what you want with associations.  There are likely a lot of complications and side-effects that would happen with relations and scopes.  Maybe this question could get answered better on the Rails mailing list.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk I know I'm digging up an old fossil here, but did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for me on Rails 3.2.1:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :finder_sql => lambda{ "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE messages.person_id=#{id} OR messages.person_id IS NULL" }
end

# person = Person.includes(:messages).first
# person.messages.loaded?  #=> true
```

Comment: unfortunately, finder_sql breaks chaining. So: Person.limit(10).includes(:messages => :image) won't work.  Or even person.messages.where(:id => 1) won't work either. I used to mention that in the ticket description, but I accidently deleted it. I'll add it back in.